# How to configure roundcube webmail with Javamailsender?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, webmail, roundcube

My program sends mails. When developing I used my gmail account to send the mails. Going in production, I should connect to the clients mail, which is a Roundcube Webmail. I set up the configuration with the information I get from roundCube. I don't get an error, but the request never gets processed.

I have tried changing ports and protocols. I also checked everything on the roundcube mail if I could find a setting that needed to be turned on to accept the incoming request.  Unfortunaltly, I cannot seem to send the mail via roundcube. To be clear, when I use my google mail settings it works fine.

Do I need to changing some setting on Roundcube? Am I misconfiguring something? Does anyone have experience with connecting to roundCube webmail and tell me what I am doing wrong? You can find below my application properties. If you need anything more, please tell me.

```
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.host=mail.domain.eu
spring.mail.username=email@email.be
spring.mail.password=password
```

Comment: Roundcube is a webmail **front-end**, it is not an SMTP server. You cannot connect to a Webmail server with JakartaaMail, you need to connect to the underlying SMTP server. You'll need to ask your provider/hoster what the correct hostnames and ports are.

Comment: The docs of the server tell me that outgoing mailserver uses SMTP, server port 587. Thus, I though I could connect on that port with smtp protocol. I also use the host stated in those docs, which is mail.host.eu.

Comment: If your application is not throwing any exception, then apparently the SMTP server accepted your message, then you'll need to ask the server administrator to check the logs of the mailserver to see what's going wrong.